# How do I display an initial value and display previous value once user has submitted the form

Tags: python, html, django-forms

This does not show an initial value but keeps previous data:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="">
```

and this does not store previous value but shows an initial value of 1:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="1">
```

Can't I have both?

What about the select element?

```
<select name="list">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the old value before it's changed. One way to do that is:

1. When a object gets focus, get its value in a temporary variable.
2. If the object value is changed, then get the value in other variable.

`var oldValue = null;`

```
var newValue = null;

$(".myClass").focus(function() {
    oldValue= this.value; // "this" is the <input> element
});

$( ".myClass" ).change(function() {
  newValue= this.value;
});

$('.myClass').keyup(function() {
   $('#newValue').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
});
```

Comment: I don't use ajax but I get what you meant. I just didn't want to assign new variable as I have a lot input form elements